# Getting 'Missing "key" prop for element in array react/jsx-key' on build

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting an error message while deploying my Next.js app on Vercel. [This](https://github.com/AfrozSaqlain/resume) is the link for my GitHub repository where I have the code.

While deploying this Next.js app on Vercel, I am getting an error message saying:

> "Missing "key" prop for element in array react/jsx-key".

I have also attached an image for the reference:

[image: The error message image]

I have checked the code but couldn't find any mistake. Can anyone please help?

I tried adding key props but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Hi Saqlain! Have you checked the below answer? Also, people are downvoting because your only code is an external link, which doesn't make your post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can edit it to past the `pages/about.js` code, for example.

Comment: Some text has been provided, but it would be better [to provide](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76795198/edit) more. See e.g. *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (includes *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*)

Comment: Came here today and found solution to my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `pages/about.js` file, you are calling React elements in arrays for the `icons` entries of the `aboutData`. [Since they are rendered in an array, they should have a unique key each, so React can distinguish them](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists). Something like this:

```
export const aboutData = [
  {
    title: "skills",
    info: [
      {
        title: "Web Development",
        icons: [
          <FaHtml5 key={1} />,
          <FaCss3 key={2} />,
          <FaJs key={3} />,
          <FaReact key={4} />,
          <SiNextdotjs key={5} />,
          <SiFramer key={6} />,
          <FaWordpress key={7} />,
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "UI/UX Design",
        icons: [<FaFigma key={1} />, <SiAdobexd key={2} />, <SiAdobephotoshop key={3} />],
      },
    ],
  },
  // ...
];
```

And at this point, you can call them as below, without having to use `map` again, as they already invoked in the array:

```
{item.icons}
```